# Search Single Value In Multiple Columns

Tags: sql

How to search value in multiple columns. For example if I have columns `FirstName`, `SecondName`, `LastName`, `Company` and I want to search either Company or person name with single input. I tried something like this but this is not very universal.

```
DECLARE @Search NVARCHAR(50) = 'Michael Jordan'

RTRIM(( LTRIM(ISNULL(Company, '') + ISNULL(FName,'') + ISNULL(SName,'') + ISNULL(LName,'')) )) LIKE + '%' + ISNULL((RTRIM(LTRIM(@Search))), RTRIM(( LTRIM(ISNULL(Company, '') + ISNULL(FName,'') + ISNULL(SName,'') + ISNULL(LName,'')) ))) + '%'
```

Comment: full text search is one way to go, would likely be more performant over doing `OR LIKE`s several times in a single query, and with the added benefit of thesaurus lookups.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OR`. For example:

```
DECLARE @Search NVARCHAR(50) = 'Michael Jordan'

SELECT
FirstName, 
SecondName, 
LastName, 
Company
FROM tableName
WHERE
FirstName LIKE '%' + @Search + '%' OR
SecondName LIKE '%' + @Search + '%' OR
LastName LIKE '%' + @Search + '%' OR
Company LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'
```